# Quadratic problems

Tags: polynomials

For the equation $f(x)=x^5+ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx-420$, why do we use $f(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-\delta)(x-\mu)$ with multiplication of the roots giving$\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\mu=420= 2\times 2\times 7\times 5\times 3$ to try to find the roots?.

Question - why does the product of the roots equal $420$?

Comment: Is this the original exercise ? It is not clear what has to be done.

Comment: I have tried to edit this to be clearer, but I am still lost with your question. Is the polynomial supposed to have integer roots? Are you supposed to find conditions for $f(4)$ to be zero? Or are the roots $2,2,7,5,3$ and you are supposed to find $f(4)$?

Comment: In ques it is mentioned that all the roots(zeroes) of polynomial are integers and greater than 1.find f(4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is:

$$f(0) = -\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\mu = -420$$

In this case this yields the answer up to signs. In general you can just as well evaluate the function in another point. E.g.:

$$f(1) = (1-\alpha)(1-\beta)(1-\gamma)(1-\delta)(1-\mu) = 1 + a+b+c+d -420$$